# Javascript framework popularity

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui, mootools, scriptaculous

Are there any resources comparing the adoption rates of the various javascript frameworks similar to [tcpi](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html)? Basically the number of sites using a particular framework on a time-line would be ideal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know of anything specifically like that, though Google Trends is probably a pretty good indication of popularity. For example, you can compare jquery and mootools:

http://www.google.com/trends?q=jquery,+mootools

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I guess adding in others such as yui, scriptaculous, etc really shows how much jquery is dominating at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, jquery is far and away the most popular. It's being distributed by Microsoft even. It's the Google of javascript libraries.

Comment: the search volumes for a framework's name as a keyword is not a fair indication its actual usage across the web--although I doubt anyone would dispute jquery's total supremacy. there just has to be a more meaningful way of measuring...

Comment: Well I'm sure Google could probably figure it out since they have every page on the web indexed... they could tell you how many reference a jquery library (not completely accurately).. but I'd say the search volume is a fairly good indicator.

Answer (score 5):

You can use google trends for that:

http://www.google.com/trends?q=javascript+jquery%2C+javascript+prototype%2C+mootools%2C+javascript+yui&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0

It's not totally accurate since it relies on searches made on google, but it gives a good idea

Comment: Useful link, although mootools is misspelled

Answer (score 1):

Take this three

[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ajax_frameworks#JavaScript)

[SurveyMonkey](http://www.surveymonkey.com/sr.aspx?sm=fXLiKcnKlD6cO5bRe961aBB6NCCWytRyY3rParAYmwA_3d)

[Another survey](http://www.kylehayes.info/2009/03/29/survey-results-javascript-frameworks/)

[image: pie chart]
<sub>(source: [getdropbox.com](http://dl-client.getdropbox.com/u/102671/kylehayes.info/jsfw_results/libraryPreference.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I ran once into following estimation methods: 
Community activity: using github - stars/forks/open/closed issues
FAQ support: using StackExchange API - questions/answered(solved)/avr. answers per question
Here I fetched these stats to compare AngularJs/Backbone/EmberJs (13.06.2014)
http://www.slideshare.net/dsheiko/java-script-framework-making-the-right-choice